# Bootstrap container width on 1 side only

Tags: bootstrap-4, containers

I'm trying to create a website using Bootstrap and I want the container width for 1 section to only apply on the left side of the page.
 I don't want to change the container width for any other sections so I thought I'd need to create a custom class, but the right hand side won't stretch to the edge like I want.

[image]

I'd like the left hand side to be in line with the container in the section underneath, but the section on top to stretch to the edge

Comment: think you missed uploading the image

Answer (score 0):

Within the container, extend the width of the your "image" div to 50% of the view width - code below:

```css
.extend {
  position: absolute;
  width: 49.8vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg);
}

.show {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container show">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
      <p>The other side... with lots of content</p>
      <p>The other side... with lots of content</p>
      <p>The other side... with lots of content</p>
      <p>The other side... with lots of content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 show">
      <div class="extend row">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```